# UITableViewCell dequeued memory is retained

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, uitableview, reusability

I have a project in which a single UITableView can have hundreds of entries (For testing purposes I promise). I'm testing out how to work with UITableViews since I've very new to them and I've encountered something I don't like.

If you use dequeueReusableCell in all its majesty it works just fine! For example I have a button that adds 100 custom cells to a custom table view. And everything is perfect

The problem is when I remove these cells! I remove the information from the database, then delete the cells from the tableView and reloadData. Everything is all good EXCEPT the CustomTableViewCells are never dealloc'd!!! Problem? I think not because I'm using the dequeue system, however since hundreds of cells are entering and exiting the table view and not a single cell is ever dealloc'd there is an inf build up of memory from unused TableViewCells!

Oh NOEZ!

Anyone find a way to deal with this? To somehow cap the reuse cell count so that say after 50 reuse cells they start to dealloc for memory's sake?

Comment: just a guess, but when you create the cells are you using 'autorelease'?

Answer (score 0):

1. You mention that you "delete the cells from tableView" and then `reloadData`. But you shouldn't delete cells. You just `reloadData` and iOS takes care of cleaning up your table and reusing your table view cells (assuming, of course, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is correctly calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`). Or were you just trying to say that you `reloadData` and you let iOS do its magic?
2. Regardless, if you include your code, we can help you find your problem.
3. I'd suggest running your code through the static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) and that may help you find your problem. Many simple leaks are immediately found with the static analyzer. You should have *zero* warnings from static analyzer.
4. If you're still leaking, use the profiler to [find your leak](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/ViewingandAnalyzingData/ViewingandAnalyzingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH5-SW22).